# IF ELSE condition in an SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query where in I have to fetch an additional param from a different table, only if a value is present in the primary table. I have tried using the if else clause, but it never works.

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT  
   hist.I_PAYT_REF AS PAY_REF,
   hist.C_USERID AS USER_ID,
   IF(@hist.I_PAYT_REF IS NULL)
   BEGIN
      SELECT 
         PAYT.I_PAYT_REQ_SUM AS PAYMENT_FILE_ID
      Join 
         SP.TSP_CP_PAYT_RQ_DTL PAYT ON PAYT.I_PAYT_REF = hist.I_PAYT_REF
   END
FROM 
   sp.TSP_CP_HIST hist
WHERE 
   hist.C_HIST_TYPE ='V'
```

All I want to do is fetch a a new parameter if the `hist.I_PAYT_REF` is not null. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yeshwanth

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @ marc_s: I apologize for not providing the complete details. I will get the details and update the post at the earliest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a left join, if `I_PAYT_REF` is null the join will not exclude the main `hist` record and `PAYMENT_FILE_ID` will be returned null anyway.

```
SELECT  
    hist.I_PAYT_REF AS PAY_REF,
    hist.C_USERID AS USER_ID,
    PAYT.I_PAYT_REQ_SUM AS PAYMENT_FILE_ID
    FROM 
         SP.TSP_CP_HIST hist left join 
         SP.TSP_CP_PAYT_RQ_DTL PAYT ON PAYT.I_PAYT_REF = hist.I_PAYT_REF 
    WHERE hist.C_HIST_TYPE ='V'
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me and that too without if condition which I am not familiar with. But the other suggestions worked too :)

Answer (score 2):

sometimes you may be need that kind of inline if, and it's a `CASE` clause, it works like inline if :)

```
select
    hist.I_PAYT_REF as PAY_REF,
    hist.C_USERID as USER_ID,
    case
        when hist.I_PAYT_REF is null then PAYT.I_PAYT_REQ_SUM
        else null
    end as PAYMENT_FILE_ID
from sp.TSP_CP_HIST as hist
    left outer join SP.TSP_CP_PAYT_RQ_DTL as PAYT on PAYT.I_PAYT_REF = hist.I_PAYT_REF
where hist.C_HIST_TYPE ='V'
```

but as @jenson-button-event says - there's no point to use `case` here - if `I_PAYT_REF` is null then `left outer join` return no records from `SP.TSP_CP_PAYT_RQ_DTL`. So you can write just

```
select
    hist.I_PAYT_REF as PAY_REF,
    hist.C_USERID as USER_ID,
    PAYT.I_PAYT_REQ_SUM
from sp.TSP_CP_HIST as hist
    left outer join SP.TSP_CP_PAYT_RQ_DTL as PAYT on PAYT.I_PAYT_REF = hist.I_PAYT_REF
where hist.C_HIST_TYPE ='V'
```

Comment: your 'case' is redundant see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Join both tables and apply `CASE` statement on your select clause.

```
SELECT  
    hist.I_PAYT_REF AS PAY_REF,
    hist.C_USERID AS USER_ID,
    CASE WHEN hist.I_PAYT_REF IS NULL
        THEN PAYT.I_PAYT_REQ_SUM
        ELSE I_PAYT_REF
    END as PAYMENT_FILE_ID
FROM    sp.TSP_CP_HIST hist
        INNER JOIN SP.TSP_CP_PAYT_RQ_DTL AS PAYT
              ON PAYT.I_PAYT_REF = hist.I_PAYT_REF
WHERE hist.C_HIST_TYPE ='V'
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `left outer join` instead of `inner join` or you can miss some data, but it depends on schema

Comment: also you have two `ON` keywords in the `JOIN` clause